# Easy modification on a jQuery url

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following url I want to include also `&id=<?php echo $id; ?>`
How can I do it?

`url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id") + "&id=<?php echo $id; ?>",
```